# How to deserialize Graphql Response

Tags: graphql, deserialization, graphql-dotnet, graphqlclient

Hi I have a graphql Response after Mutating

```
{{
 "carCreate": {
   "car": {
     "id": "TestId"
   }
 }
}}
```

I want to Desealize it I am using The following Code

```
var graphQlClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(AppConfig.GraphQlUrl, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
```

I have tried to resolve with the following code

```
var response = await graphQlClient.SendMutationAsync<CarCreate>(request);
```

My Created Model is :

```
 public class Car
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CarCreate
    {
        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should be something like this,

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class Car
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class CarCreate
    {
        public Car car { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public CarCreate carCreate { get; set; }
    }
```